# What is the French word for scientific calculator and what does 'la formule de calcul' mean ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

What is the French word for 'scientific calculator'?

Also, what does 'la formule de calcul' mean?

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/calculator

Comment: I think Google Translate would (and did) translate those two terms quite well.

Answer (score 8):

scientific calculator = calculatrice scientifique.

MAIS ATTENTION : Je crois que le Collins commet une confusion avec le sens 3 de "*formule de calcul*".

Les collaborateurs contemporains du Collins sont sans doute trop jeunes pour avoir connu l'ancêtre de la calculatrice que les anglais appelaient déjà "*calculator*" et que les français nommaient [règle à calcul](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Sliderule_2005.jpg/550px-Sliderule_2005.jpg).

Et comme, en traduction automatique, la confusion formule / règle est fréquente, je me permets de persister et signer : ***Règle à calcul*** et non *formule de calcul*.

---

NOTA BENE: [Le pédigrée de Peter Shor](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1312/peter-shor) donne un crédit certain à son objection apportée en commentaires.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason that Collins got it wrong. I think they were trying to translate an obsolete meaning of *calculator* that predated electronic calculators. As in the book (found in Google books) "The agriculturist's calculator; a series of tables for the use of all engaged in agriculture or the management of landed property." And quite possibly they got the right translation, but *formule de calcul* is as obsolete in French as this meaning of *calculator* is in English.

Comment: And a *règle à calcul* was a *slide rule* in English, not a calculator (and is as obsolete as the *formule de calcul* meaning of *calculator*).